# Android Studio how can I use mega sdk in Windows

Tags: android, sdk

I want to add access to MEGA cloud in my Android application, I download examples from https://github.com/meganz/sdk.git.
In ReadMe file says

```
Download the prebuilt libraries (`libmega.so`) along with its corresponding Java classes from [here](https://mega.nz/#!zktVFAyS!ZzvOYnU-I6cmKgc3_rA-UIJh98suyLAM6BPF7_57BoM).
```

But file isn't there anymore. And in my understanding all examples and SDK was built for develop on Linux system, can I use this SDK to develope if I have Windows? Did someone do it?